# IOS application is not starting - i can only see the splash screen then it fade out without starting

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a React-Native project.
This project begun with Expo then it has been ejected switched to react-native.
Last week i have updated an expo library that was available in it, i begins to get errors and i was not able to start the project anymore.

What i have made, i have removed all expo libraries used, and i have succeeded to start it up on android...
But on IOS, it's running without debug problems, but when i start the app it shows the splash screen then it fadeout without starting the first app screen.
It seems like onSplashscreen.hide, its not opening the app first screen

this is the package.json file (and the changes i have made (git))
[image]

This is the appDelegate.m
[image]

```js
{
  "name": "~~~~~~",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    
    "open:android": "open -a /Applications/Android\\ Studio.app ./android",
    "compile": "tsc --noEmit",
    "debug": "open 'rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.17.2",
    "@eva-design/eva": "^2.0.0",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^1.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.10.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.10.0",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "^5.0.0",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.0.2",
    "class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "class-validator": "~0.11.1",
    "color": "^3.1.3",
    "expo-app-loading": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "^0.6.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
    "lottie-react-native": "3.5.0",
    "mobx": "5.15.7",
    "mobx-react": "6.3.1",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.17.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "native-base": "^2.15.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "~0.63.4",
    "react-native-change-icon": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "1.5.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-markdown-renderer": "^3.2.8",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "~4.0.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.2",
    "react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.11",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-smooth-pincode-input": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^0.14.3",
    "react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "react-native-webview": "10.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "reanimated-bottom-sheet": "^1.0.0-alpha.22",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "@types/color": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.162",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-dom": "~16.9.8",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "@types/react-native-signature-capture": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.4",
    "@types/yup": "^0.29.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.6.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "eslint": "^7.12.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.10.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.0",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "prettier": "^2.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

This is the appdelegate.m

```js
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

//  #import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistry.h>
//  #import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMNativeModulesProxy.h>
//  #import <UMReactNativeAdapter/UMModuleRegistryAdapter.h>
// #import <EXSplashScreen/EXSplashScreenService.h>
// #import <UMCore/UMModuleRegistryProvider.h>

#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>

@interface AppDelegate () <RCTBridgeDelegate>

//  @property (nonatomic, strong) UMModuleRegistryAdapter *moduleRegistryAdapter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *launchOptions;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
  //  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  // [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}

- (RCTBridge *)initializeReactNativeApp
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:self.launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge moduleName:@"main" initialProperties:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return bridge;
 }

//  - (NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *)extraModulesForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
//  {
//   NSArray<id<RCTBridgeModule>> *extraModules = [_moduleRegistryAdapter extraModulesForBridge:bridge];
//   // If you'd like to export some custom RCTBridgeModules that are not Expo modules, add them here!
//    return extraModules;
//  }

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
 #else
  return [[EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance] launchAssetUrl];
 #endif
}

// - (void)appController:(EXUpdatesAppController *)appController didStartWithSuccess:(BOOL)success {
//   appController.bridge = [self initializeReactNativeApp];
//   EXSplashScreenService *splashScreenService = (EXSplashScreenService *)[UMModuleRegistryProvider getSingletonModuleForClass:[EXSplashScreenService class]];
//   [splashScreenService showSplashScreenFor:self.window.rootViewController];
// }

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please, post the code as text not as image

Comment: Thank you @PtitXav for ur response. I have added these as text

Comment: In didFiniishLsumching with option you init react if DEBUG and use Ex… init else.

Comment: Thank you @PtitXav for you reply. i tried to remove the if statement and run it without the statement but still the same thing ,,,,,,     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  
  initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
   [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  return YES;
}

Comment: You have other #if DEBUG that use Ex… : sourceUrlwforBridge

Comment: Hello @PtitXav.. really appreciate your help.. I have replaced the code by the bellow _italic_`- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
 #ifdef DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
 #else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
 #endif
}` and still have the same problem